# How to order rows with linked parts in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a table **A** with columns: **id, title, condition**

And i have another table **B** with information about position for some rows from table A. Table B have columns **id, next_id, prev_id**

How to sort rows from A based on information from table B?

For example, 
Table A

```
 id| title
 ---+-----
 1 | title1
 2 |  title2
 3 |  title3
 4 |  title4
 5 |  title5
```

Table B

```
 id| next_id | prev_id
 ---+-----
 2  | 1      | null
 5  | 4      | 3
```

I want to get this result:

```
id| title
 ---+-----
 2 | title2
 1 |  title1
 3 |  title3
 5 |  title5
 4 |  title4
```

And after apply this sort, i want to sort by **condition** column yet.
I've already spent a lot of time looking for a solution, and hope for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add weights to your data, so you can order accordingly. This example uses next_id, not sure if you need to use prev_id, you don't explain the use of it.

Anyway, here's a code example:

```
-- Temporal Data for the test:
CREATE TEMP TABLE table_a(id integer,tittle text);
CREATE TEMP TABLE table_b(id integer,next_id integer, prev_id integer);
INSERT INTO table_a VALUES
(1,'title1'),
(2,'title2'),
(3,'title3'),
(4,'title4'),
(5,'title5');
INSERT INTO table_b VALUES
(2,1,null),
(5,4,3);

-- QUERY:
 SELECT
    id,tittle,
    CASE -- Adding weight
        WHEN next_id IS NULL THEN (id + 0.1)
        ELSE next_id
    END AS orden
FROM -- Joining tables
    (SELECT ta.*,tb.next_id
    FROM table_a ta
    LEFT JOIN table_b tb
    ON ta.id=tb.id)join_a_b
ORDER BY orden
```

And here's the result:

```
id  |   tittle  |   orden
--------------------------
2   |   title2  |     1
1   |   title1  |   1.1
3   |   title3  |   3.1
5   |   title5  |     4
4   |   title4  |   4.1
```